# ActiveMQ CMS - redelivery counter

Tags: activemq-classic, activemq-cpp

Is there a way to know how many times a specific message has been redelivered?

There's the method `getCMSRedelivered()` of the class `cms::Message`, that works alright but returns a boolean.
There's also the method `getRedeliveryCounter()` of the class `activemq::core::commands::Message`, but that's an inner class I'd rather not access directly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's retrievable through the reserved vendor property in your Message:

```
getIntProperty("JMSXDeliveryCount");
```

or:

```
getLongProperty("JMSXDeliveryCount");
```